# MVC Design for an app using RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, design-patterns, restkit

I'm trying to create an app that follows MVC as closely as possible using `RestKit`. The goal is to incorporate `RKObjectMapping` and `RKObjectManager` so that my objects can be loaded using `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/object" delegate:self]`.

In my current design, I have the following:

```
Objects
- MYBaseObject : NSObject
- MYObjectA : MYBaseObject
- MyObjectB : MYBaseObject
...
ObjectControllers
- MYBaseObjectController : NSObject
- MYObjectAController : MYBaseObjectController
- MYObjectBController : MYBaseObjectController
...
ViewControllers
- MYBaseViewController : UIViewController
- MYViewController1 : MYBaseViewController
...
```

I also have introduced a delegate called `MYBaseObjectControllerDelegate` that acts as an adapter/wrapper for different things that may involve delegation (like asynchronous requests), as well as in case I decide to not use `RestKit` in the future.

1) Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following in `MYViewController`:

```
self.arrayOfMYObject = [MYObjectA allObjectsWithDelegate:self];
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to get that sort of thing to work, however, using delegation. The problem is that I need to somehow `return` the response value and there is no way I can think of to do that using only delegation.

2) I would like to know where the various `RestKit` declarations of `RKObjectMapping` and such should reside. Should they live in the respective controllers for each of the Objects, or should they live in the objects themselves? What would be an appropriate structure?

Being new to `RestKit` I would like to get it as "right" as possible the first time around to avoid major refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/RestKit/RKGithub as an example app for a possible starting point.

I have successfully adapted this structure to my own applications.

Under this structure, the mapping sits at the root level and is then called on by the controllers.